# How does ARM switch to svc mode in IRQ handler?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, arm, interrupt

The following code snippet is taken from linux v2.6.11. Something similar is present in v3.8 as well.

```
mrs     r13, cpsr
bic     r13, r13, #MODE_MASK
orr     r13, r13, #MODE_SVC
msr     spsr_cxsf, r13                  @ switch to SVC_32 mode

and     lr, lr, #15
ldr     lr, [pc, lr, lsl #2]
movs    pc, lr                          @ Changes mode and branches
```

Check out the following link for the actual file:
http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.11/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S

I think writing into the mode bits of CPSR can change the current ARM mode. But how writing into SPSR (instead of CPSR), has resulted in switching to SVC_32 mode?

(or) Is something happening in the last instruction "movs pc, lr". Could someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `mov` or `sub` instruction with the 'S' suffix and the program counter as its destination register means a exception return.

It copies the contents of the SPSR to the CPSR and moves the value of the source register into the program counter (in this case, the link register).

In your example, this effectively sets the mode to SVC mode and returns from the function in one go.

There's more information on this in the [ARM reference manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjaiacfg.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am answering the `SPSR` Vs `CPSR` question here.

`CPSR` is `user/system` mode register, and doesn't exist in other modes, like `fiq` or `irq` modes. Whereas, `SPSR` exists in `fiq` and `irq` modes. On a mode change `CPSR` is copied into `SPSR` and the changed mode has to use `SPSR` to make any changes to the current status of the processor. `SPSR` is not available in user mode. And any changes made to `CPSR` in non-user mode won't take effect.

```
CPSR - Current Program Status Register
SPSR - Saved Program Status Register
```

Comment: CPSR is accessible in all modes (partially in user mode).